# Filling custom table in dataset with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset

As my question above, I want to create a custom datatable in a dataset (I mean I don't drag and drop the existed datatable or view in the .MDF file to the dataset) and fill it with a stored procedure. Is there anyway to do it? Please give me any reference link or tutorial.
For more information, I'm using LinQ to SQL to work with my database
Thanks and regards

Comment: this is actually a very simple task try doing a google search on `C# How to Populate a DataTable from a Stored Procedure`

Comment: sorry, i've just edited @MethodMan

Comment: you are aware that `Google` exist correct..?

Comment: as you see my added Information, i'm using linQ to SQL to call stored procedured so how can I mapping the return row?

Comment: Justin try this in a google search `C#  LINQ and return result as Datatable`
 this is not a code factory site

Comment: sorry for my bad, english is not my native language so it's difficult for me to explain

Comment: and one more thing that i didn't asked for how to code, but i ask about the idea or anyway to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) to [fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx) the table. Set it's [`SelectCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`CommandType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx)  to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Optional TableName");
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Connection-String Here"))
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("StoredProcedureName", con))
{
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // you don't need to open/close the connection with Fill
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataSet.Tables.Add(dt);
}
```

Comment: but my table in dataset is custom table, how can I mapping the result of stored procedure to my datatable in dataset?

Comment: so, what I have to do is just create my custom table with columns that suite to what my stored procedure return? For example my stored procedured return like (Select A, B, C From X) the my custom table has column name A, B, and C and it will be mapped automaticly?